# vector allocation confusion

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a Tree class of the following type

```
class Tree{
   private:
        Node *root;                         // trie root node 
        unordered_map<int, vector<Node*> > *index; 
        unsigned long long size;
        int count;
    public:
    ................
};
```

I am having a vector of the following type

```
vector<Tree> vect;
```

With the above declaration I am encountering a segmentation fault when a number of nodes are added to each of the Tree.

But the same works perfectly when I use the following declaration

```
vector<Tree*> vect;
```

and allocate each Tree* pointer explicitly on the heap using new

The segmentation fault seems as if it occurs because of excessive memory utilization of the stack.

And from a previous question in stack overflow I was told that in  the first declaration each Tree object will be allocated on the heap.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal executable example that reproduces the error (see http://sscce.org). Without that, any answer is just a guess.

Comment: Chances are that when you're using raw pointers You Wrote It Wrong. You will almost surely need correct copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors; given that you didn't post those, it stands to reason that the error lies there.

Comment: I understand. I thought this was a long shot, but the code was kind of huge.

Comment: @Phelodas: If the code is quite long, strip it down to the *minimal* set of functions that will reproduce the error.  This is good exercise in debugging, and chances are you will find your error.  Then you can come back here and ask why it behaves the way it does and/or how to fix it.

Comment: @Phelodas: It takes some work, but the idea is to simply remove stuff from your code until the error goes away. When the error goes away, you know that the last thing you removed is probably causing it (although sometimes it is not). This is already valuable information. Now just throw away anything that is not related to the problem, and then you should have a manageable amount of code that you can post here.

Comment: @Bjorn and Andre Thanks for the tips and yes it was because I was overlooking the copy constructor. I apologize if I wasted any of your time on this trivial problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your little code, I guess you have problems in your copy constructor and operator=. Each time you add new item in your vector, there is a copy invocation. In the case of vector of pointers, there is no problems, but with your class, you will have problems with your pointer and map. Implement these methods correctly and try again.